# Finding two products inside a document in key value form

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document file like this

{
"Animal":{
"name": "cow",
"Color": "white",
"Type": "a"
}
}

{
"Animal":{
"name": "buffalo",
"Color": "black",
"Type": "b"
}
}

{
"Animal":{
"name": "cow",
"Color": "black",
"Type": "a"
}
}

I wanna make query to get all distinct
{
Cow : black ,
Buffalo: white,
Cow : white

Comment: please update your question and make more clear

Comment: You can get distinct values using an aggregation query `$group` pipeline stage. See [Aggregation Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/) for usage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.